# Delete notification channel without id

Tags: android, push-notification

My app has a bug where it sends different push notification and up until now every notification got its own channel ID, so the user has got for every new notification a new channel which he can then enable/disable by toggle. This bug is now fixed but I want to delete the old unnecassary channels programmatically and I found the way do it like this:

```
// The id of the channel.
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
val id: String = "my_channel_01"
notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id)
```

But since every channel got created by a random generated ID and this ID has been  discarded I can't delete the channel by his ID.

Is there a way to list all channel IDs a user got or any other way how I can delete old channels without knowing the ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

obtain full list of all already created channels by calling [getNotificationChannels()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getNotificationChannels())

iterate through this list and call [`deleteNotificationChannel(id)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#deleteNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)) for unnecessary/unknown channels (`NotificationChannel` have [getId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#getId()) method)

Comment: where is this deleteNotificationChannel(id) function? In flutter?

Comment: sadly don't have idea, tags of these questions aren't mentioning flutter, and I'm not using it

Answer (score -2):

have you tried `cancelAll()` method if notification manager

```
notificationManager.cancelAll()
```

Comment: this is for canceling/removing notifications, not channels